# How to add a custom device into google Home

Tags: esp32, google-home, google-smart-home

I've created a smart device with esp32 using adafruit IO and integrated it with google assistant using IFTTT. This way I can control the device using custom voice controls from google assistant or access the adafruit IO panel and toggle the device.

The problem is that I can't find a way to add this device into the google home app, to control it alongside my other smart switch.

Apparently, there is a google home SDK, but I'm not sure how I could integrate my esp32 to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use Google's [smart home platform](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview) and build a cloud integration. You may be able to follow Google's [codelabs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/codelabs) to get started or check out one of the existing code samples.